# Python - Get coordinates of important value of 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, coordinates

I would like to determine an angle from an image (2D array).
I can get the coordinates of the point whose intensity is maximum with "unravel_index" and "argmax" but i would like to know how to get an another point whose intensity is high in order to calculate my angle.
I have to automatise that because i have a great number of images for post-treatement

[image]

So for the first coordinates, i can do that :

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import unravel_index

t = unravel_index(eyy.argmax(), eyy.shape)
```

And i need an another coordinates in order to calculate my angle...

```
t2 = ....

theta = np.arctan2(t[0]-t2[0],t[1]-t2[1])
```

Comment: The method that you have in mind will fail: the pixels with the highest intensity can well be perfectly aligned (let's say horizontally), even for a non-horizontal line. I would advise that you fit a line to your data (weighted linear regression).

Comment: have you a post to advise me? :) and i m looking for that

Comment: You can look up linear regression, there are tons of resources on the web. Now, if you want to do this efficiently with NumPy, this is a separate question for which I have no reference off the top of my head; it's definitely doable efficiently, though.

Comment: i think i will try in a first time with masked values! and then i will try with that if doesn t work. I have already fit with leastsq but without weight...thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

What you could try is to look into the Hough Transform ([Wikipedia - Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform)). The Hough Transform is a tool developed for finding lines and their orientation in images.

There is a Python implementation of the Hough Transform over at [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hough_transform#Python).

I'm not sure if the lines in your data are distinct enough for the Hough Transform to yield good results but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your array in a masked array, find the pixel with the maximum intensity, then mask it, then find the next pixel with the maximum intensity.

Comment: Yep interesting i will try that! ;)

Comment: Not easy as you say, it finds a pixel aligned with previous pixel :/

Comment: This makes complete sense. Using a weighted linear regression is really much better. An orthogonal distance regression would even be better, as it is independent of the system of coordinates (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/odr.html). This should take just a few lines, with NumPy and SciPy.